# Kernel panic trying to install Debian Linux on Dell computer

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-panic, dell-optiplex, linux-server

When I try to install Debian Linux (newest stable as of 6.2.2013, x64) on a Dell OptiPlex 740 I keep getting this error message right after I choose "Install" from the main menu (the hdd is empty):

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(254,32)
```

I have tried using a liveCD and that won't boot up either, screen just goes almost white with a white cursor blinking in the top left corner.

Windows 7 Ult x64 installs fine on the same computer. I have installed Debian on several computers (servers) before this and never had any problems. What's wrong?

Comment: What happens on the lines above this error message? It will usually give you some more info about the partitions it's found and what-have-you. Also, what type of drives are you using?

Comment: Isn't the optiplex an UEFI one? There where a lot of issues in the last weeks with samsung (+others) uefi laptops and Linux (up to no longer working samsung notebooks)

Comment: Have you checked the md5sum of the iso you downloaded?

Comment: @Xyon: There is just this one line. The drive is your common SATA2 hdd.

Comment: @Offler: How can I check this?

Comment: @terdon: I have not. Doesn't utorrent do that anyway? I got the bittorrent copy.

Comment: @Akke - Either look at the online documentation or give us exact details of the model your using.

Comment: @Ramhound it's the one in the middle: [Product Broschure](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/740_customer_brochure.pdf)

Comment: Unless we know what motherboard is used not sure we can answer this question.  Sounds like you should contact Dell for support and ask them if your computer is using a UEFI BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'll try and look at the mobo for the model no.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

- Try booting from USB, not CD, as sometimes CD drives cannot be detected on startup
- In the BIOS, set the SATA controller mode to AHCI, potentially IDE, but never RAID, and also "AHCI (Linux)" often does not work with Linux.

Comment: I've done the SATA controller configuration on many (10+) other motherboards, but can't seem to find it on this one. I made a USB netinst drive and it still gives me the same error msg. What do?

Comment: Check [the manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_optiplex_desktop/optiplex-740_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf), on page 8 it talks about AHCI settings.